# How to chose the instance to be de-allocated in Azure Cloud Worker role?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-management-api

I am seeking to improve the autoscaling behavior of an existing CPU-intensive app implemented in .NET and hosted as an Azure Worker Role. Currently, auto-scaling is controlled by the app itself through the [Management API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arunrakwal/archive/2012/05/10/azure-scale-application-increase-or-decrease-the-number-of-role-instance.aspx) by adjusting the number of role instances. However, I do not control which instance gets de-allocated. In order to be more efficient, I would like to specify which instance is intended to be de-allocated, instead of just killing one instance at random.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

answer that was wrong removed, see correct links below in comments from @Joannes.  not deleting as I don't want to remove his comment.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure this point is still valid? After I posted my question, I came across http://gauravmantri.com/2013/10/16/a-new-version-of-windows-azure-service-management-api-is-available-with-delete-specific-role-instances-and-more-goodies/